# Can I make Windows inbuilt Steps Recorder (PSR) to store ticks level timestamp?

Tags: windows, events, timestamp, screenshot, screen-scraping

I am using Windows "Problem Steps Recorder" (PSR) for my application and need to store each ActionSet (Screenshot) with timestamp to tick level granularity. At present PSR html file gives me each action in the following format:

```
  <EachAction ActionNumber="120" Time="11:43:44 AM" Pid="8992" ProgramId="0000da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709" FileId="0000f53c3e9453e8e4352db97fddbea5bc1357a3d2a2" FileName="ECLIPSE.EXE" CommandLine="ECLIPSE.EXE">
    <Description>User left click on "Close (button)" in "PyDev - J6VideoMining/src/utils/constants.py - Eclipse"</Description>
    <Action>Mouse Left Click</Action>
    <CursorCoordsXY>1349,7</CursorCoordsXY>
    <ScreenCoordsXYWH>0,0,1366,768</ScreenCoordsXYWH>
    <UIAStack>
      <Level BoundingRectangle="1317,0,47,20" ControlType="50000" Name="Close" LocalizedControlType="button" />
      <Level BoundingRectangle="16,-5,1350,28" ControlType="50037" LocalizedControlType="title bar" />
      <Level BoundingRectangle="-8,-8,1382,744" ClassName="SWT_Window0" ControlType="50032" FrameworkId="Win32" Name="Eclipse SDK" LocalizedControlType="window" />
    </UIAStack>
    <ScreenshotFileName>screenshot0120.JPEG</ScreenshotFileName>
  </EachAction>
```

Here, the timestamp is given as Time=`"11:43:44 AM"`. At present I am being able to convert it to millisecond level - PSR time is in local timezone. I am converting it to UTC date, and then getting ms.

One workaround I can do is, find another screenrecorder. But I haven't found any, which can get screen details like PSR (you can see in the `<UIAStack>` tag in the html snippet given above. Another crude way would be use another screenrecorder along with PSR, and timesync the event screenshots. But I need to avoid additional timesync error overhead, and also running multiple screen recorders.

I am using PSR as part of an application, where the tick granularity is essential.

Any pointer is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a Python way to solve this issue. Instead of relying on PSR, I am now directly working with the Windows DLLs that PSR uses internally. For this I am using a MSAA Python client library called [PIYA](https://github.com/eeejay/pyia). It uses a DLL wrapper called comtypes.